# Does drug have differential impact on different age dependent variables?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics

I have the following experimental setup.

Conditions:

cell age: young, old

treatment: control, drug

Different genome readouts (methylation, acetylation, ...) were taken for these conditions. Given genome function is location dependent the signal was summed and log transformed into equal bins across the genome (45000 consistent bins for each conditions).

Cell age (old vs young) introduces changes in a subset of bins, i.e. some bins gain methylation signal and some bins loose methylation signal in old vs young samples. These gains and losses are correlated or anticorrelated across different measurements in controls, i.e. methylation gains in bin#1 are associated with acetylation loss and vice versa in bin#2, while a third readout is gained in bins gaining methylation. In other words a net change in one readout is generally associated with a net change in the other readout.

How do I test whether the drug significantly affects the net change of say methylation changes in old vs young compared to acetylation and other readout changes in old vs young?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's "the age-related dynamic range of a variable"? Are changes in variables comparable in a biological sense, not just in a mathematical sense? For example do expect that 1% reduction in oxygen have the same effect on health and well-being as 1% reduction in metabolism?

Comment: I don't know whether the variables are causal to age/health even I suspect some of them might (if that is what you were asking). I just know they either increase or decrease with age. Given I only have two time points I can also not comment on rate.